# Issue with calling a function to fetch the text from xml document using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, oxygenxml

I want to call the variable(referencedObjects) or call the function to print the text inside value element.

I am getting the result without the function but If I add a xsl function and a variable inside, I am not able to fetch the variable hence not getting the required result.

Current error is function undefined

Need a solution to call the function to fetch the text inside value element.

Basically, I need to transform the input to the expected result.

Any help would be appreciated

Input

```
<Metadata id="WTPart_1398662" source="wt.part.WTPart|com.ptc.PHBase|com.ptc.PHModel">
         <Property token="number">
            <Value>PH_U-HD2</Value>
         </Property>
         <Property token="number">
            <Value>PH_U-HD3</Value>
         </Property>
 </Metadata>
```

**Expected**

```
<p>PH_U-HD2</p>
<p>PH_U-HD3</p>
```

**XSL code**

```
<xsl:stylesheet  
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:my="http://itcinfotec.com/my-namespace"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    

    <xsl:function name="my:getRealUDProducts" as="xs:string">
           <xsl:param name="path"/>
       <xsl:variable name="referencedObjects">       
        <xsl:for-each select="//Object/Metadata[@source='wt.part.WTPart|com.ptc.PHBase|com.ptc.PHModel']">
         <xsl:value-of select="Property[@token='number']/Value" />            
        </xsl:for-each>     
    </xsl:variable> 
    </xsl:function>

     <xsl:template match="/">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="my:getRealUDProducts(.)"></xsl:value-of>
        </p> 
    </xsl:template>    
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: and how are your invoking the XSLT code?

Comment: Currently testing locally but eventually this XSLT code will be invoked in publishing configuration file in downstream system.

Comment: which xslt processing are you using?   Testing HOW locally?  Please be specific about details.

Comment: Consider the xml file as a input

Comment: I am editing the question, I got the confusion. Thanks

Comment: I have edited the question and XSL as well, please let me know, if its still not clear.

Comment: I am using oxygen editor, I am taking the input xml as mentioned in the question and transform using the XSL mentioned in the question to get the output. Currently output is empty because of function undefined error.

Comment: You can achieve what you need without any function.

Comment: I know I can achieve it without a function, but having a function is a requirement when it goes to downstream system. So only need help on this.

Comment: Basically, Solution with a function is must.

Comment: Your function does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

Your function body has nothing but a variable that is not even used. And you don't use the node you pass in at all, inside of the function there is no context item defined (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#function-result: "Within the sequence constructor, the focus is initially absent; this means that any attempt to reference the context item, context position, or context size is a dynamic error.").

I would expect the processor to give that error as soon as you try to use that variable as it tries to access a context item in e.g. `//Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code clearly isn't going to work for all the reasons described by @MartinHonnen. But can we help you to write code that is going to work? For this we have to try and understand what you are trying to achieve.

Getting from your input to your desired output is trivially easy:

```
<xsl:template match="Property/Value">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

So why are you making it so complicated?

You say several times that having a function is a requirement. Well, it's a strange sort of requirement. What is the purpose of the required function? What part of the processing is the function needed for? It's very easy to take any part of a working stylesheet and wrap in a function, but without understanding why you want this, we can't do it for you.

Let me make some guesses. Looking at your non-working code and trying to read your mind, perhaps the input actually consists of multiple `Metadata` elements inside an `Object` element and you are trying to select one of them based on the value of its `@source` attribute. In that case the function you want might look like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="input" select="/"/>
<xsl:function name="my:getRealUDProducts" as="xs:string">
   <xsl:param name="source"/>
   <xsl:sequence select="$input/Object/Metadata[@source=$source]
                         /Property[@token='number']/Value" />            
</xsl:function>
```

But I may have guessed completely wrong.

Comment: You guessed it right, there will be will many **Metadata** elements in an **objects** element, So the idea is to have many variables inside a function, during integration in publishing server config file they want to leverage function call to fetch all the variable or a particular variable value. I gave them a solution to fetch the values from a variable directly but the integration folks wanted a solution with a function, which would be easy for them to integrate. I don't have any further information about why they need a solution with function.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch the variable from a function EX. **my:getRealUDProducts($referencedObjects)** based on my XSL code?

Comment: No, the only way you can get information from a function is to return it as the function result. Local variables declared within a function are out of scope outside the function (as in every other programming language I know of...)

Comment: Could you please help me, how to return it as a function result in my case?

Comment: What is "it"? What do you want your function to return?

Comment: I want to call the variable/param from a function to return the return the text inside value, Is there a way it can be done?

Comment: I don't understand why you need a variable or why you need a function. It would be much better if we could talk about what you want to achieve, not about the programming constructs you want to use.

Comment: I will handle this request, I will try to convince them with a solution without a function. Thank you so much!!! Could you please help with a another issue, which I am stuck, here is the URL **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76357707/conversion-of-normal-filter-statement-to-hybrid-filter-statement-using-xsl**